# Why does tsc command emit an error even though vite command works?

Tags: typescript, tsc, vite, esbuild

I'm trying to run `tsc` on a React project scaffolded with Vite -- all other commands run fine and the project loads and builds successfully, but when running `tsc` I get this error:

```
../../node_modules/@types/download/index.d.ts:9:10 - error TS2614: Module '"got"' has no exported member 'GotEmitter'. Did you mean to use 'import GotEmitter from "got"' instead?

9 import { GotEmitter, GotOptions } from "got";
           ~~~~~~~~~~

../../node_modules/@types/download/index.d.ts:13:58 - error TS2315: Type 'GotOptions' is not generic.

13     interface DownloadOptions extends DecompressOptions, GotOptions<string | null> {
                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can see it's related to a types module that I didn't even install myself. Any idea where this comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could try to put

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
```

into your tsconfig file. This will skip the type check for node_modules.

Comment: A perfect solution!